# Reproducibility of a poisson noise realisation over a sequence

Tags: numpy, random, random-seed, poisson

Here is my problem :
I have a sequence of float int values (it's a simulated astronomical image but that is not important). I need to get a poisson realisation of this sequence.
Then I want to change a few values/pixels and get again a poisson realisation of this new sequence.
I need that the unchanged pixel get the same noise.

```
import numpy
from numpy.random import default_rng,randint
import copy
import pylab

# Create the two lists (with only few pixels changing)
a0 = numpy.random.randint(low=0, high=1e6, size=10000).astype('float')
a = numpy.random.randint(low=0, high=30, size=10000).astype('float')
b = copy.copy(a)
b[a0>9.9e5] += 1e6

# Run poisson on them
gen1 = default_rng(seed=1234)
gen2 = default_rng(seed=1234)
resa = gen1.poisson(a)
resb = gen2.poisson(b)

# Plot the difference (reshape to 2D image to better see the differences)
pylab.imshow(resa.reshape((100,100))-resb.reshape((100,100)), vmin=-10,vmax=10)
```

With the numpy implementation of poisson (numpy.random.poisson), even if the Seed is the same, the sequence will differ even for the pixels that are identical. The reason is that the Poisson noise is calculated in a conditional loop, which gets a new random value and returns when this value is above some threshold based on lambda. Therefore, after two different pixels, the default_rng (or RandomState) will be different in the two sequences and will give different results even for identical pixels.

Is there an implementation of poisson that would garanty the same number of draw on the RandomState generator whatever the signal level ? Or do I have to tweak the code to do it myself (by looping of draws to always reach a predefined loop iterations) ?

Comment: Did you have a try at the very last Poisson variate generation algorithm mentioned in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Random_drawing_from_the_Poisson_distribution) ? It takes only a single draw, possibly at some (large) cost in performance.

Comment: *"I need that the unchanged pixel get the same noise"*. Same as in the first time? That means the final value will be the same, in which case draw your new distribution and then set the values of `resb` where `a0 <= 9.9e5` to those from `resa`.

Comment: In the real application (not this simplified mockup) those two series won't be generated at the same time ... so I won't have access to resa when I will compute resb. I need a poisson generator that I can operate with reproducibility.
The way I do it now (with a huge slowdown in runtime) is to instantiate as many RandomState as there are elements in the sequence. But this is rather ugly !

Comment: what is a float int value?

Comment: If you still have access to `a` before changing the pixels, you can recreate `resa`. Otherwise, no idea.